# R - group specific list items

Tags: r

I have a character data that looks like this:

```
  x= c("Clause 1 - AGREEMENT. Buyer agrees to buy, and Seller agrees to sell, the Property described below on the terms and conditions set forth in this contract.",
       "Clause 2 - Buyer. Buyer, will take title to the Property described below:",
      "Item 2.1 - Seller. Seller, is the current owner of the Property described below assignable by Buyer without Seller’s prior written consent.",
       "Clause 3 - Inclusions. The Purchase Price includes the following items: ",
       "Item 3.1 - Fixtures. If attached to the Property on the date of this Contract, the following items are included unless")
```

I am tryng to group all Items into the Clauses in a list. Basically, I want it to do this

```
x[grep("Clause . - ", x)]= c(x[1], paste(x[2], x[3]), paste(x[4], x[5]))
```

and this

```
x= x[grep("Clause . - ", x)]
```

but dynamically. How can I do it without specifyng the list items i want to combine? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

First strip out just the numbers:

```
> nums <- gsub("^..* (\\d+\\.*\\d*) -..*$", "\\1", x, perl = T)
> nums
[1] "1"   "2"   "2.1" "3"   "3.1"
```

Group them by dropping the decimal place:

```
> nums <- as.integer(nums)
> nums
[1] 1 2 2 3 3
```

Loop over these groupings and paste them together:

```
> grouped <- tapply(x, nums, paste, collapse='\n')
> cat(grouped[2])
Clause 2 - Buyer. Buyer, will take title to the Property described below:
Item 2.1 - Seller. Seller, is the current owner of the Property described below assignable by Buyer without Seller’s prior written consent.
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! That solves 70% of my problems. But to solve the others, is it possible to use the index of `grep("Clause . - ", x)` to generate the variable that you called nums, instead of `gsub`? something like rep numbers until it finds a non missing number

Comment: Can you post an example where this isn't working? The pattern I posted matches at least on digit possible succeeded by a period and zero or more other digits

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem adapting the answer provided by Zelazny. With the data:

```
> x= c("Clause 1 - AGREEMENT. Buyer agrees to buy",
        "Item 1.2 - Seller agrees to sell",
        "Item 1.2 - the Property described below",
        "Item 1.3 - on the terms and conditions set forth in this contract",
        "Item 1.4 - If attached to the Property on the date of this Contract",
        "Item 1.5 - the following items are included:",
        "I - property",
        "II - car",
        "III - motorcycle",
        "Clause 2 - Buyer, will take title to the Property described below:",
        "Item 2.1 - Seller. Seller, is the current owner of the Property",
        "I - this is binding contract",
        "Item 2.2 - by Buyer without Seller’s prior written consent.",
        "Clause 3 - The Purchase Price includes the following items",
        "Clause 4 - property will be transmited",
        "Clause 5 - as discribed in",
        "Each party is signing this agreement on the date stated opposite that party’s signature.",
        "city, date")
```

First find the items that are clauses:

```
> f= grep("Clause . - ", x)  
> f  
[1]  1 10 14 15 16
```

As the `rep` dosn't allow a list of times, loop over and repeat the previous item number for all the missing itens:

```
> nums= f  
> for (i in 1:length(f)-1){  
>    a= f[i+1]-f[i]-1 #times to repeat the number  
>    nums= c(nums, rep(f[i], times= a))  
> }  
> sort(nums)  
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10 10 10 10 14 15 16
```

Add all the numbers after the last clause:

```
> nums= sort(c(nums, (1+f[length(f)]):length(x)))
> nums
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10 10 10 10 14 15 16 17 18
```

And finally group the items in the clause:

```
> grouped <- tapply(x, nums, paste, collapse='\n')  
> cat(grouped[1])  
 Clause 1 - AGREEMENT. Buyer agrees to buy
 Item 1.2 - Seller agrees to sell
 Item 1.2 - the Property described below
 Item 1.3 - on the terms and conditions set forth in this contract
 Item 1.4 - Fixtures. If attached to the Property on the date of this Contract
 Item 1.5 - the following items are included:
 I - property
 II - car
 III - motorcycle
```